# How we can decode emoji,special character in python?

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have a text file that contain lines like :

```
        Name; Country
       josuÃ© sÃ©gura;FR
       Dr GÃ©rald KIERZEKâš¡ðŸ‘¨â€âš•ï¸;FR    #contains emoji
```

I need to decode this text in UTF-8, I don't find a solution in python.
I find on the internet a solution in javascript, but I never use javascript, I need a solution in python that makes it possible to decode all text (all lines) in UTF-8.
Thank you very much

Comment: See [emoji](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/)

Comment: I want to decode this text on UTF-8 format

Comment: I want just to transform this text in UTF-8 format  to make it more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is text that was originally encoded as UTF-8 but has been decoded with an 8-bit encoding (perhaps cp1252 or some other Windows encoding, perhaps latin-1).  This is known as [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

It can be correctly decoded by encoding as latin-1 to get bytes, then decoding as UTF-8.

```
> s = '33;josuÃ© sÃ©gura;FR'
>>> s.encode('latin').decode('utf-8')
'33;josué ségura;FR'
```

Comment: Do you know what that line looked like before it got messed up?

Comment: Also, do you know how the file got like this?  Was it downloaded?  Scraped from a webpage?  Sent from a computer with a different operating system or language settings?

Comment: There isn't a guaranteed solution to fixing mojibake; if you can't provide more information about the origin of the text then there isn't anything further that can be done.